# Can you tell me how to use a for loop in my code?

Tags: python

```
def get_odds(first=0, stop=10, step=1):
    number = first
    while number % 2 == 1:
        yield number
        number += step
    for i in range(1,10):
        third_value = get_odds[4]
        number = third_value
        print(third_value)
```

I want to return the odd numbers from range(10), so that's why I coded like this. But now, I want to know 'How to use for loop to find and print the third value returned'.

Comment: `list(range(1, 10, 2))`.

Comment: There is some problem with your `get_odds` generator function, since `get_odds[4]` does not make any sense. What is the line `third_value = get_odds[4]` supposed to do?

Comment: I code that way so that I can print the third value of `get_odds`, but I realized it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to use a generator function to find the odd numbers in the range from 0 to 10 and you need to use a 'for' statement in it, and you need to be able to state the third odd value, then I think this is what you are after. But none of the answers given by me or the Stack Overflow respondents will do you any good until you understand *why* they work. (Comprehension is its own thing, and is not the same thing as a generator function.) This is a great opportunity to learn. Study them all until you know why they work, how to write your own, -and- why your code did not work. Good luck with this Hojin. And have fun!

```
def get_odds(first=0, stop=10, step=1):
    number = first

    for x in range(first, stop, step):
        number += step
        if number %2:
            yield number

numbers = []
print("The odd numbers in the range from 0 to 10 are:")
for num in get_odds():
    print(num)
    numbers.append(num)
    
print("-"*25)
print("The third odd number is "+str(numbers[2])+".\n") #(Computers count from 0)
```

Comment: You're right. I wanted to use a generator function to find odd numbers in the range(10). Also, Thank you for your advice. I really appreciate that.

Comment: You are welcome. You are off to a great start on a life-long passion. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Use list-comprehension

```
odd_list = [x for x in range(0,11) if x%2 != 0]
```

or use recursion,
or use a state machine (just kidding,but it can be done)

best suggestion?
google it.

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension is your best bet

```
>>> [ i for i in range(10) if i%2 !=0][4]
9
```

This expression returns the 3rd element in a list between the numbers 0 and 10 that are not divisible by 2.

Answer (score 1):

My Answer : `[ i for i in range(1,10) if i%2 !=0][4]`